# How to render a template after promise resolves?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I want to return a template to be rendered in parent after resolving the promise. I know that value can't be returned from promise. How can I render the template once the template data is received?

In the following example, ContentPane is the parent which lists all the template to be rendered. In Films, network call is made and accordingly template needs to be rendered.

```
ContentPane.prototype.getTemplate = function(){
    let template = `
        <div class="contentPane" id="contentPane">
        ${new Films().render()}
        </div>
    `;
    return template;
}


Films.prototype.render =  function(){
    var template =  this.getTemplate();
    template.then(function(val){
        return val;
    })
    //based on the value resolved by promise,
//appropriate template should be returned to parent
}

Films.prototype.getTemplate = async function(){
  //make network call
  //create template based on server response
}
```

Comment: Notice that the function `getTemplate` does not return a promise. It just returns the template string in a synchronus manner. Therefore you cannot use `.than()` on it

Comment: @NirWeber I have updated the question with getTemplate function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try aync-await operation....

```
const ContentPane = function() {}
const Films = function () {}

ContentPane.prototype.getTemplate = async function(){
  let template = `
      <div class="contentPane" id="contentPane">
      ${await new Films().render()}
      </div>
  `;
  return template;
}
Films.prototype.render =  async function(){
  var value =  await this.getTemplate();
  return value;
}
Films.prototype.getTemplate = async function(){
   return new Promise((res, rej) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
           res('123');
        }, 1000);
    });
}
new ContentPane().getTemplate().then(template => {
  console.log(template);
});
```

Comment: Following this approach will result in async-await for the complete chain of components, which will hit the performance. Is there any other approach possible?

Comment: You're going to have to wait for the film before rending the content. No way around that.

Answer (score 0):

I write an example. `ContentPane.prototype.getTemplate` can return a promise, then you can get the template from `then` callback function. like this `new ContentPane().getTemplate().then(template => {
    console.log(template);
  });`

```
  const ContentPane = function() {}
  const Films = function () {}

  ContentPane.prototype.getTemplate = async function(){
    const filmsTemplate = await new Films().render();
    let template = `
        <div class="contentPane" id="contentPane">
        ${filmsTemplate}
        </div>
    `;
    return template;
  }


  Films.prototype.render =  function(){
    var template =  this.getTemplate();
    return template.then(function(val){
      return val;
    })
    //based on the value resolved by promise,
    //appropriate template should be returned to parent
  }

  Films.prototype.getTemplate = async function(){
    //make network call
    //create template based on server response
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve('123')
    })
  }

  new ContentPane().getTemplate().then(template => {
    console.log(template);
  });
```

Comment: Following this approach will result in async-await for the complete chain of components, which will hit the performance. Is there any other approach possible?

Comment: Because it's async.You can add the loading animation.

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve your problem like this.
it work for me:

```
<items ref="items" :all="all" @remove="removeItem" />
```

and ==>

```
this.$api.productCategories.delete(item.id , true)
  .then(res => { 
    this.all = this.all.filter(i => i.id !== item.id) this.$showSuccess(this.$t('productCategories.productCategoryRemoved'))
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.items.reinit()
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    this.$showError(this.$getLocaleErrorMessage(err, 'productCategories'))
  })
```